# How do you compile taglib on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, taglib

I'm trying to compile an example from taglib 1.8 on ubuntu 12.04 http://taglib.github.com/

I copied an example into the directory with `fileref.h` and tried compiling it with g++

```
cp taglib-1.8/examples/tagreader.cpp taglib-1.8/taglib
cd taglib-1.8/taglib/
g++ -o testreader.exe tagreader.cpp 
tagreader.cpp:28:21: fatal error: fileref.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

How do I go about compiling taglib on ubuntu?

**EDIT**

Hi Lukas - Thanks for the response.  I want to make a simple cli program to write id3 tags to mp3 files (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216094/how-to-write-a-taglib-program-to-write-the-id3v1-title-and-artist-and-the-id3v2).

So far I've just untarred taglib 1.8.

**(1)** How do I build taglib on ubuntu 12.04?  When I tried your second command I got the following error

```
Package taglib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `taglib.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'taglib' found
tagreader.cpp:28:21: fatal error: fileref.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

However the file `taglib.pc` does not even exist. The file `taglib-1.8/taglib.pc.cmake` does exist.

**(2)** Do you know how I can get `taglib.pc from it?

Comment: Can you try with `g++ -I. -o testreader.exe tagreader.cpp`. Btw why `.exe` for an executable in ubuntu?

Comment: Same error message unfortunately.  I don't know why I appended .exe.  `In file included from tagreader.cpp:28:0:
./fileref.h:29:19: fatal error: tfile.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Comment: No it is not the same error message. Now it is able to find `fileref.h`. But now `fileref.h` includes another header `tfile.h`, which `g++` is unable to find. If you check, this file is inside `toolkit` directory. Add another `-I toolkit` to `g++`.

Comment: so I ran the following command `$ g++ -I. -I toolkit/ -o testreader.exe tagreader.cpp` but now I get the error `./taglib_export.h:44:27: fatal error: taglib_config.h: No such file or directory`  When I do a search for `taglib_config.h` the only file that shows up is `taglib_config.h.cmake`.  How do I create `taglib_config.h.make`?

Comment: Sorry - I meant "How do I create `taglib_config.h` from `taglib_config.h.cmake`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you want to just install the examples, or your own program using TagLib?

You can build the examples as part of building TagLib with:

```
cmake -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .
make
```

If you want to build your own program and you already have TagLib installed, use `pkg-config` to get the necessary command line options, for example:

```
gcc -o test test.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --cflags taglib)
```

For this to work, you need to have TagLib installed. You can build it from sources, but if you don't necessarily need TagLib 1.8, just install it from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install libtag1-dev
```

Then you will have the TagLib libraries, header files and `pkg-config` files available in the standard location and you can easily build your own application.

Also, you don't need to write application that simply writes artist name and title. The tagwriter example does that. Or you can use this https://github.com/lalinsky/tagger if you need something more complicated. It might serve you as an example, if nothing else.

Comment: Hi Lukas - Thanks for your response.  Sorry for the newb factor but can you check out my edit?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have built TagLib. You need to do that first and you also need to install it.

Comment: Thanks lucas, I'm using the example tagwriter.  However for some of my mp3's I get the message `TagLib: MPEG::XingHeader::parse() -- Xing header doesn't contain the total stream size.` even though I'm able to successfully write the tags to the mp3s.  What is causing taglib to choke in this case? How do I prevent it?

Comment: @user784637 I'm getting the Xing Header error, as well. Can you share how you got rid of it? Or link to what helped you?